# How to perform a successful segue programmatically from SKScene to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, presentviewcontroller

I have tried several different answers and have yet to find an answer that works.

I keep getting

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I have a SKScene called selectUpgrade that is in my GameViewController and I am trying to segue to a UIViewController called MissileUpgrade.

```
var vc2 = MissileUpgrade()  //trying to get to this UIViewController
var gameVC = GameViewController()  // currently in a scene in this UIViewController
```

I am calling this in my scene to segue

```
func goToMissileUpgrade() {
    gameVC.presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

These are in the same storyboard. If I set MissileUpgrade as the initial VC it will load fine so I know it has nothing to do on that end. I am lost on why this is not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are currently in `GameViewController`, shouldn't your code be `self. presentViewController` instead of `gameVC.presentViewController`?

Comment: I am in a SKScene that is called selectUpgrade so when i do that I get the error "selectUpgrade" has so member "presentViewController"

Comment: Ok, what line is it crashing on? Is `gameVC` or `vc2` nil?

Comment: gameVC.presentViewController(vc2, animated: true, completion: nil)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, don't use `presentViewController` use `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Give your Segue an Identifier in the Storyboard, then refer to it in the code like so:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifierHere", sender: self)
```

Comment: it does not give me that option? I am calling this inside a skscene. Could this be why?

Comment: I tried        `gameVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToMissileUpgrade", sender: gameVC)` but i get error `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Missile_Mayhem.GameViewController: 0x1490949e0>) has no segue with identifier 'goToMissileUpgrade'`